# compiled.phpがプロジェクト作成時に生成されてしまう

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel5で開発をしています。

プロジェクトを作成すると、自動的に`php artisan optimize`が実行され、`vender/compiled.php`が生成されます。

この状態だと、boot時に、`compiled.php`が優先して読み込まれ、自分が追記したサービスプロバイダの内容が読み込まれません。

その為、毎回、プロジェクト作成後に`compile.php`を削除しています。

この現象に気付いたきっかけは、`EventServiceProvider`にイベントハンドラの設定を追加したのに、ハンドラが発火されず、ハマったことです。

optimizeはパフォーマンスを上げる有効な手段ですが、デプロイ時に必要になるもので、開発時には必要ないと思っています。

そこで、質問です。

- `compiled.php`がプロジェクト作成後に生成される理由は何かあるでしょうか？
- 毎回プロジェクト作成後に手動で`compiled.php`を削除しなくてすむ、回避方法はあるでしょうか？
- 上記の私の認識に何か間違えはあるでしょうか？その為に招いている現象でしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compiled.phpがプロジェクト作成後に生成されるのは不具合でした。

Laravle v5.1で改善されました。コンポーザー経由でのプロジェクト作成、Laravelインストーラでのプロジェクト生成の両方で改善されています。

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/2ac993f8d369c0ca367accc93714ad960995f91e
https://github.com/laravel/installer/commit/e93e688c914d535fc7a7fbbfddf0f80a426147c8

なお、Laravelインストーラはv1.2.1にUpdateする必要があります。

```
$ composer global update
$ laravel -V
Laravel Installer version 1.2.1
```

また、v5.1からcompiled.phpの出力先が、bootstrap/cache/compile.phpに変更になりました。

Answer (score 1):

> compiled.phpがプロジェクト作成後に生成される理由は何かあるでしょうか？

パフォーマンス向上のためです。

> この現象に気付いたきっかけは、EventServiceProviderにイベントハンドラの設定を追加したのに、ハンドラが発火されず、ハマったことです。

.env の `APP_DEBUG` が `true` ならば、 optimize 時にあなたの作成したクラスが compile されることはなく、[代わりに clear-compiled が実行されます](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php#L70)。

.env を確認してみてください。

> 毎回手動でcompiled.phpを削除しなくてすむ、回避方法はあるでしょうか？

.env の `APP_DEBUG` を `true` に設定してください。

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled
```

でも削除することができます。

> 上記の私の認識に何か間違えはあるでしょうか？

下記URLに詳しく書いてありますので読んでみてください。

[Laravel Recipes日本語版 | パフォーマンス改善するためにフレームワークを最適化したい](http://recipes.laravel.jp/recipe/50)

Comment: ここでは `\`\`\`` で囲んでもコードブロックにならないため、インデントする必要があります（参考 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code）。ところで「下記URL」が書かれていないようです。

Comment: @unarist さんありがとうございます。

下記URLはこっちでした。

Laravel Recipes日本語版 | パフォーマンス改善するためにフレームワークを最適化したい : http://recipes.laravel.jp/recipe/50